# Why does the question verifier false flag beautified Stack Snippets code as not being code?

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

The last time I answered a question using Stack Snippets, I ended up having to edit the answer in such a way I'd have to realign most of it by a tab. This was the first time I noticed Stack Snippets could beautify code, so I tested it out. What I found instead was the code alignment was so narrow, the announcements on the side of the screen warned me to indent more.

I don't have anything against coding styles, but I find it silly users can be slapped on the wrist for using features that would otherwise be beneficial to them occasionally.

Comment: You *might* be conflating Markdown code block indents with JSFiddle indents. Every code block follows the same four-spaces-per-line rule in order to be formatted as a <pre><code> by the Markdown parser. Pasting directly from JSFiddle doesn't automatically fill in those four spaces for you, because that is a separate formatting element entirely.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about, and I cannot reproduce the behavior you appear to be describing. I suppose you don't get these "announcements on the side of the screen" after a certain reputation level?

Comment: I was editing it from the small "edit the snippet"  under the "run the widget" button on the  edit page, but not on the JSFiddle site itself. It wouldn't surprise me if that were the case though.

Comment: I'll see if I can get it to trigger again @CodyGray

Comment: I was only able to pull it off again one time. I entered the fiddle editer, replaced the code's indentation with 8 space indents before saving, then opening the fiddler again, running the beautifier, and saving.

Comment: In the mean time, I did find a bug I could reproduce. Still trivial, but using unreasonable large tabs breaks some of the indentation: http://i.imgur.com/VAkK2eQ.png. When I first ran into the other, i was indented away from the screen simiarly to the way I was her.

Comment: ...Are you talking about [Stack Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? That's not jsFiddle.net, which is a completely different web site with no relation to Stack Overflow.

Comment: ....yes. My bad